# New Gvim installation on Microsoft Windows appears in a very small window

Tags: vim

I just performed a fresh installation of Gvim on my Microsoft Windows based system. A very small business card sized Gvim window pops up. The text size on the menu is small but readable, but both the button icons and text in the body are illegibly tiny. How can I make Gvim render properly?

Comment: My guess is that this user is using a very high resolution monitor (2180 lines or greater) and that Vim is not using OS guidance regarding scaling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `:set guifont=*` to find a font that you like, then edit your `_gvimrc` (`:e $USERPROFILE/_gvimrc`), then insert on a new line

```
set guifont=
```

and after the equals, while still in insert mode, press/type <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd><kbd>=</kbd><kbd>&</kbd>`guifont`<kbd>[Enter]</kbd>

...and if you're not in insert mode but on the `=` character, you can type `"=&guifont`<kbd>[Enter]</kbd>`p`.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this same problem and here is the solution I came up with:

Open gvim.exe's properties -> Compatibility -> Override high DPI scaling behavior -> Scaling performed by -> System Enhanced